# Convert QR code into WMF stream with FreePascal

Tags: type-conversion, qr-code, freepascal, wmf, codetyphon

I need to create a DLL to accept GPS coords >> and convert them into QR codes.
The output should be a WMF stream. *(It will be printed with Delphi 7 FreeReport)*

Installed CodeTyphoon, can generate the QR code, but:

- How do I **convert** it into a WMF stream?

This component seems to be read-only: [fpVectorial](https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/fpvectorial#WMF)

```
var QQ: TBarcodeQR;
begin
  QQ.Text := 'geo:44.140315,-73.746625';
  QQ.Generate;
  // ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by wp:
[Lazarus forum link](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,50888.msg372481.html#msg372481)